# Bower and gulp is not installing

Tags: node.js, windows, gulp, bower

I've installed Node 64 bit on my Windows system. Now I am trying to run the command `npm install -g bower`, but it's never getting completed.

I only see a line jumping on slide, but nothing happens after that.

I waited it for like 9 hours but nothing. Can somebody please help me sort it out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: No error. I only see a jumping line

Comment: do you have speed internet connection

Comment: it's like 90kbps downloading speed

Comment: can you test with high speed internet connection

Comment: Ok, let me test it and I'll let you know

Comment: I think I had this in my Windows 10 few months ago. I don't remember how I fixed it, but into the things I would try, would be: 1. Try to install locally before globally (just to check if it works). 2. Restart the windows. 3. Try in Powershell, in case you're currently trying in CMD  - or vice-versa (I think this is what worked - but not sure). Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the science behind it but what I did was just

- uninstalled `Node Server`.
- deleted the folder in Program Files directory.
- ReInstalled node server

And then bang. It worked -:)